# Prove that the open cover of a finite union of closed intervals has a finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis

just looking for quick validation on my super simple proof for the above. This should be really simple, but just want to make sure I haven't made or a mistake, or if anyone wants to feel free to post an alternative proof.

Let $a_n < b_n$ for $n = 1, \ldots, N$ and consider the finite union of closed intervals, $S = \cup_{n=1}^N [a_n, b_n]$. Show any open cover of $S$ has a finite subcover.

**My proof is**: Because $S$ is the union of closed intervals, according to the Heine-Borel Theorem, an open cover of a closed interval has a finite subcover, meaning the finite subcover of the open cover of $S$ can be the union of $N$ finite subcovers of each interval in $S$, $[a_n, b_n]$. Therefore, any open cover of $S$ has this finite subcover.

Comment: Seems legit. A finite union of finite subcovers is a finite subcover.

Comment: Your approach is correct and that's the way to go.

Comment: I recommend writing things more formally, since this kind of proof may lead to mistakes on more advanced topics. Correct still.

Comment: Got it! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given that you can use Heine-Borel theorem you should of course use it.

The alternative to your solution is to use the fact that a finite union of (bounded) closed interval is a bounded closed set and therefore fulfils the requirements of Heine-Borel theorem (given that you don't only have a constrained version of it requiring the set to be a closed interval). However that would also require you to know that a finite union of closed set is closed and a finite union of bounded sets is bounded.